# How to export a MySQL table based on table date?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

How do I export a database but export the tables based on their date created?  B/C I'm facing this issue where when exporting this database, since some of the tables have foreign keys and linked to other tables by their keys, how do I export to overcome that issue?

Comment: basically i want to export the tables in a database in order by date created, that way i shouldn't run into any foriegn/primary/or any other type of key related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to export the tables of a database in order by date created you can use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) Scheduled backup, where you have:

- **An option to add a TIMESTAMP to the backup file name**
- An option to backup a complete database or only individual tables
- An option to backup to a single file or to split the backup into more files
- An option to store the backup files in a single folder or a 'folder tree'

There is also an option to SET foreign_key_checks = 0; while taking backup so that you don't run into any foreign key related issues ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think what you want is to add a couple of lines to the import file when inserting rows:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
-- insert rows
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

This way the inserts can occur in any order.